# how to: overflow ellipsis for images, to show the three dots "..."

Tags: html, image, overflow, ellipsis

How can I use the three dots "..." functionality of

```
overflow:"hidden"; 
white-space: "nowrap";
text-overflow: "ellipsis";
```

for a bunch of **IMAGES** inside a `<td>` with pure CSS?

thanks,
Doron

Comment: Well, you could start by removing the quotes. Other than that, tables are difficult if you want to restrict their width. Your example works fine with a `div` if you give it `max-width:100%` (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Tq3jK/)), but not so much luck with a table.

Comment: The quote marks in your code are invalid CSS. And how do you expect a **text** ellipsis to work with **images**??

Comment: @Spudley images act just like words, normally. They neatly sit in line on the baseline, etc. And as you see in my fiddle, they behave nicely.

Comment: @MrLister - yes they do. But you're not going to get an image breaking nicely in the middle with `...` the way text would, if that's what he wants. But in any case, it's not clear what he does actually want.

Comment: @Spudley He did say "a bunch of images" which make me believe he wanted to break in between them. But you're right, it's open to interpretation. Let's wait until he responds.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response.. @Spudley is right! I ment a break between the images.. For example let's say the following brackets are images, and the curly represents my <td>: {[][][][]...} Can this be accomplished using pure CSS?